# The signal $\frac{e^{j10\pi n}}{10}$ is periodic/aperiodic?

Tags: signal-analysis, periodic

How to verify the function
$$
\frac{e^{j10\pi n}}{10}
$$
is a period/aperiodic function ?

**My attempt:**

$\omega_o=10\pi\implies f_o=\omega_o/2\pi=5$, which is a rational number. So the given function is periodic.
The fundamental period, $N=2\pi\frac{m}{\omega_o}=2\pi\frac{5}{10\pi}=1$

Is it the proper way to approach the problem?

Comment: You'll find that the signal, as written, is equal to $\frac{1}{10}$ for all $n$. Is it possible that you have a typo?

Comment: @JasonR Yes good catch Jason. So is a DC signal periodic, since in itself it is a waveform that repeats at regular intervals? I haven't really thought of that before but by definition a waveform is periodic if f(n+m) = f(n) for some m, so on that definition his waveform is periodic. Is there a formal exclusion to such cases?

Comment: I suppose I would say it's periodic, as it does meet that condition. I'm not aware of any formal classification for whether a DC signal is periodic; this is engineering, after all. Such arguments are never productive. :)

Comment: @DanBoschen a discrete time constant signal, $x[n]=K$ for all $n$, can be considered to be periodic with any period $N$ that satify $x[n+N] = x[n]$ and the minimum of such $N$ is $N=1$. No formal problems here. A continuous time DC is periodic with any $T$ and since by definition the period is to be selected as the minimum of such numbers $T$ such that $x(t+T) = x(t)$ , then for a continuous time DC there may be some objections to whether to classify DC as a periodic signal or not.

Comment: @Fat32 Thanks that is helpful and I think you answered the OP (you should post your response below). So interesting point that a continuous DC signal would be periodic with t=0  (or at least a limit at t goes to 0), meaning it's periodic rate is also DC!

Comment: @DanBoschen The way I prefer to put it is, a DC signal is periodic but it doesn't have a fundamental period, defined as the smallest $T>0$ such that $x(t)=x(t+T)$.